# callback for google oauth not redirecting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-oauth

My google oauth is working properly, the data is saved and all the console.logs answer everywhere but there is one problem after serializing my  webpage is not redirecting to the react application

problem is in callback

```
Router.get(
  "/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google"),
  (req, res, err) => {
    if (err.name === "TokenError") {
      res.redirect("/"); // redirect them back to the login page
    }
    user = req.user;
    console.log("[googleRoutes.js] callback : ", user);
    res.redirect("localhost:3000");//problem lies here
  }
);
```

anthe other code is :

```
const passport = require("passport"),
  GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy,
  keys = require("../key"),
  User = require("../User"),
  UserSession = require("../UserSession");

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log("[Serializing Google] :", user.id);
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  User.findById(user.id).then(user => {
    console.log("[Deserializing Google] :", user.id);
    done(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback"
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log("profile :", profile.id);
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
      if (existingUser) {
        //we already have a record wih the given profile ID
        console.log("user existing google");
        done(null, existingUser);
      } else {
        //we don't have a user record with this ID, make a new record
        const user = await new User();
        user.username = profile.displayName;
        user.googleId = profile.id;
        console.log("google id is saved");
        user.save().then(theuser => {
          done(null, theuser);
        });
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: Is `'localhost:3000'` different than `'/'`?

Comment: Yes '/' goes to localhost:4000 which is server host but thats not the problem here